# Scanning DynamoDB table not showing results from the column specified in ProjectionExpression

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, alexa-skills-kit

i'm trying to scan the DynamoDB tale so that i fetch only filtered items.
myTable has 3 columns:L timestamp (String, PK), colors (String), userId (String)

```
var docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

var params = {
    "TableName": "myTable",
    "ProjectionExpression": "colors, userId",
    "ExpressionAttributeValues": {":val": userId},
    "FilterExpression": "userId = :val"

};

console.log("Scanning table.");
docClient.scan((params), function(err,data){

    if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); 
    else console.log(data); //success response
});
```

> 2018-05-22T08:04:21.395Z   baac6d92-5d96-11e8-ae78-bd04c275acf5    Scanning table.
>   2018-05-22T08:04:21.672Z    baac6d92-5d96-11e8-ae78-bd04c275acf5    { Items: [ { userId: 'amzn1.ask.account.XYZ' } ], Count: 1,  ScannedCount: 2 }

As a result i'm only getting value(s) from userId column. The column 'colors' is completely  ignored.

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting `ProjectionExpression` attributes in `ExpressionAttributeNames`. Check out the following snippet

```
var docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

 var params = {
  ExpressionAttributeNames: {
   "#colors": "colors", 
   "#userId": "userId"
  }, 
  ExpressionAttributeValues: {
    ":val": userId
  }, 
  FilterExpression: "userId = :val", 
  ProjectionExpression: "#colors, #userId", 
  TableName: "myTable"
 };

console.log("Scanning table."); 

docClient.scan(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); 
    else console.log(data); //success response
});
```

Note the `#` and `:` must be present on `ExpressionAttributeNames` and `ExpressionAttributeValues`, respectively.

Comment: Thx for the advice, however after implementing your changes i get another error ValidationException: ExpressionAttributeNames contains invalid key: Syntax error; key: "userId"

Comment: Thank you, if possible edit my answer with the fix you provided